# Network not assigning values ip's over 60

Tags: ip

In a network connection,the network has 60 people connected,when he assigns an ip to 61th person,it doesnt get assigned.
Even in a CLASS C server,255 should be the minimum range of ip's assigned,any idea why is that happening?

Comment: There are no more network classes, this is an antiquated term. You are referring to a /24 subnet.

Comment: What is the new standard ?

Comment: CIDR: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIDR, http://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-subnetting-work

Comment: @MarkM - thanks for pointing that out. I litereally screamed inside my head and saw red when I saw ANOTHER `class` based question.

Comment: @Farseeker: I thought of you :)

Comment: @squill - naawww I have a reputation! This makes a certain kitty proud.

Answer (score 5):

This seems like the DHCP server is only configured for 60 addresses. You would have to reconfigure it to make more addresses available.

But I get the feeling I am doing your homework for you, right?

Comment: My friend runs a network and he told me that he has this problem so i discussed.

Answer (score 0):

Sven is right, however you did not indicate whether the DHCP server was Unix or Windows or "other" - How you have your network Class C laid out eg: 1-10 reserved 11-20 network devices, 21-40 printers 41-100 DHCP 101 - 255 VPN Tunnels and static devices...

With a DHCP server, unless you have a very tiny infrastructure, you would not let DHCP have 1-255.  Is this a test?  ;^)

Comment: Please do not call a /24 a Class C. There haven't been network classes for many years.

Comment: "Old timer" habit, Mark. I been in the biz since the 80's - running multi-user Xenix BBS's in Silicon Valley before the internet was opened up for private use. /24 = Class C - I stand corrected..  I trust you had little else you found repugnant with my response?  ;^)